# Rgd: htaccess unable take in full stop

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

If my url is

```
http://www.example.com/book/book1/35.1/1
```

the url return 404 not found

if my url is

```
http://www.example.com/book/book1/34/1
```

the url is okay

Below is my .htaccess file

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /book

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1&num=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I not sure why full stop doesn't seem to work, how can I change the htaccess to handle this issue.

**Thanks**

Comment: Or simply `([\d.]+)` instead of `(\d+)`.

Comment: `[\d.]+)` will allow for multiple periods though, or just a single period and no numbers.

Comment: Well, checking the general format might be enough. The target script would still need to validate the actual value, in the same way `9999999` might also be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your regex is only looking for numbers between the slashes. You can change that to

```
^([^\/]+)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/([^\/]+)$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oF7aZ1/2

Which will find any continuous numbers or a decimal then numbers (`(?:\.\d+)`). I'm not sure if the htaccess supports non-capturing groups though (**Update**:  reading through it appears Apache 2 does support non-capturing groups).

So perhaps

```
^([^\/]+)\/(\d+\.?\d*)\/([^\/]+)$
```

would be better. The flaw with this approach is that the numbers after the `.` would be optional. So for example `3.` would be valid, that isn't really a number.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oF7aZ1/1